# Avoid proceed-to-checkout-button text refreshing to default text in WooCommerce cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

In WooCommerce, in my Storefront child theme, I edited the code in `proceed-to-checkout-button.php` to change the wording from "Proceed to checkout" to "Checkout":

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}
?>

<a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_checkout_url() ); ?>" class="checkout-button button wc-forward">
    <?php esc_html_e( 'Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
</a>
```

But when the user changes product quantity in the cart page, then the button text goes back to default "Proceed to checkout".

Is there a filter or where to edit this updated text?

---

**EDIT - Problem Solved**

> The issue was related to a specific cart option in [WooCommerce Better Usability pro](https://pluggablesoft.com/woo-better-usability-pro/) plugin where the option *"Display text while updating cart automatically"* requires to be disabled *(unselected)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overriding `proceed-to-checkout-button.php` file, should use the following instead:

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'custom_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
function custom_button_proceed_to_checkout() {
    echo '<a href="'.esc_url(wc_get_checkout_url()).'" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">' .
    __("Checkout", "woocommerce") . '</a>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works on last WooCommerce version under Storefront theme.

> Now as you have done a lot of customizations in your templates or may be you are using some plugin in cart page for customization, the problem can remains due to those customizations.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, thanks but with your code I still have "Proceed to checkout" after updating the product numbers. https://staging.hemen-biarritz.com/cart/

Comment: @Louis This is due to your numerous customizations, as I test everything on last WooCommerce version under Storefront theme (with a child theme) and it works perfectly even if I change the  quantity in cart. So your issue seems to be related to cart fragments (Ajax). Mots of your questions issues here on SackOverFlow are due to that customizations you are doing since some time now.

Comment: Can we chat in private messages ?

Comment: I just did send you a message on your "contact me" link. with my phone number. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

This file proceed-to-checkout-button.php is calling from the function woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout() hooked to action 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout' - you can find it in woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php

So, You can override the function woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout() - just add this to your functions.php

```
/**
*   Change Proceed To Checkout Text in WooCommerce
*   Add this code in your active theme functions.php file
**/
function woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout() {
    
       $new_checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
       ?>
       <a href="<?php echo $new_checkout_url; ?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">
       
       <?php _e( 'Go to Secure Checkout', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
       
<?php
}
```

I'm guessing that maybe the ajax button's update comes from the parent theme.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's exactly the same result : the first display is right (it shows what your code modifies) but when updating the product quantity, the buttons refreshes and the text is back to default "Proceed to checkout"