# Modify "Proceed to checkout" button without shipping method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

I would like to change the text of the "Proceed to checkout" button without shipping methods, using the codes "[Prevent access to checkout without shipping method in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065801/prevent-access-to-checkout-without-shipping-method-in-woocommerce/61068237#61068237)" and "[Avoid proceed-to-checkout-button text refreshing to default text in WooCommerce cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64313266/avoid-proceed-to-checkout-button-text-refreshing-to-default-text-in-woocommerce/64313706#64313706)".

This is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
function modify_checkout_button_no_shipping() {
$chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );    
if( empty( $chosen_shipping_methods ) ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'modify_checkout_button_no_shipping', 20 );
    echo '<a href="'.esc_url(wc_get_checkout_url()).'" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">' . __("Alternate checkout text", "woocommerce") . '</a>';
}
}
```

Any help is apprecciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add_action` must be inserted outside the `modify_checkout_button_no_shipping` function.

Otherwise your code works correctly.

Try with this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'modify_checkout_button_no_shipping', 1 );
function modify_checkout_button_no_shipping() {
    $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    // removes empty values from the array
    $chosen_shipping_methods = array_filter( $chosen_shipping_methods );
    if ( empty( $chosen_shipping_methods ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
        echo '<a href="'.esc_url(wc_get_checkout_url()).'" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">' . __("Alternate checkout text", "woocommerce") . '</a>';
    }
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*