# Code broken after PHP update - Modify "Proceed to checkout" button without shipping method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, code-snippets, shipping-method

i'm have been used this code below (from [Modify "Proceed to checkout" button without shipping method in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66821711/modify-proceed-to-checkout-button-without-shipping-method-in-woocommerce)), and worked fine for 3 months with Code Snippets Plugin. But after running PHP and Wordpress/WooCommerce updates my Cart page is broken and not working if this code is enabled.

Here this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'modify_checkout_button_no_shipping', 1 );
function modify_checkout_button_no_shipping() {
    $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    // removes empty values from the array
    $chosen_shipping_methods = array_filter( $chosen_shipping_methods );
    if ( empty( $chosen_shipping_methods ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
        echo '<a href="'.esc_url(wc_get_checkout_url()).'" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">' . __("Informe o seu CEP para prosseguir", "woocommerce") . '</a>';
    }
}
```

And here this error (summed up from error_log):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: array_filter(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given in /../public_html/wp-content/plugins/code-snippets/php/snippet-ops.php(505) : eval()'d code:5
```

Any help is apprecciate.

Comment: A quick fix would be `array_filter( $chosen_shipping_methods ?? [] )`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'modify_checkout_button_no_shipping', 1 );
function modify_checkout_button_no_shipping() {
    $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    // removes empty values from the array
    if(is_array($chosen_shipping_methods)){
        $chosen_shipping_methods = array_filter( $chosen_shipping_methods );
    }
    if ( empty( $chosen_shipping_methods ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
        echo '<a href="'.esc_url(wc_get_checkout_url()).'" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">' . __("Informe o seu CEP para prosseguir", "woocommerce") . '</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `isset()` since you know it's defined and you're checking the the type with `is_array()`.